# How to get absolute positioning on image elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm displaying some images on my page in Image Elements. However with different screen resolutions they move to different places on the page.

How should I write the below code so that my div/elements will remain absolutely positionned  and won't change in different resolutions?

```
<div class='imageElement2'> 
<a href='#' title=''><img alt='' height='364' src='http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7209/6978440877_10b1fcffc4_o.jpg' width='940'/></a>
</div> 

<style> 
.imageElement2 {
width:1020px; height:400px; overflow:auto;
position:absolute; z-index:2; left:50%; top:0%;
margin-left: -510px; margin-top:40px; text-align:center;
visibility:visible;}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, especially with `margin-left: -510px`.  What is happening now?  can you post some screnshoots and also schematics of what you want?  Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: The "margin-left:-510px" is my image's position on the website, what's so weird about that?

Comment: you can use "position:relative" instead of absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
left: 50%; top: 0%;
```

and replace them with a fixed px levels like

```
left: 50px; top: 0px;
```

because 50% means the position at 50% of the width of the browser area.

So you see, on a 1024 screen the div will be at 512 and on a 1366 screen the div will be at 683.

HINT: Never use % if want an "absolute" positioning on any browser.

HINT: if you are trying to position the div in the middle of the screen just apply these styles

```
width: your-desired-width-on-any-browser px;
margin: auto; //to bring it middle
//additionally you can add "top: X px/%/em; to position it vertically.
```

Have a good day.

Comment: I see, you're absolutely right, I shouldn't have had the "%" in there. However I tried fixing it and my image is still moving around when I view my site from other computers, or when I use "ctrl"+"scroll wheel" has same effect...is it possible for an image to stay put? Seems like everyone who views my site will not see it the way I intended it to be if they have a different monitor resolution... ;-;

Comment: You can use position: fixed in your styles. Any way can you give the like to your website where you exactly have this "problem". It would be nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the best way would be to make a wrapper div with at width and height, elements in this div will not be affected by changing page width, you will just get a scroll.

This should do the trick, just append it to a wrapper element.

```
 .imageWrapper { width: 500px; }
```

However a screendump of what you want, would be great!

Comment: ok grabbing links to images so you can see my problem one sec

Comment: Ok so here's what the top of my website is supposed to look like: http://i40.tinypic.com/15bjuw.png

Comment: And this is an example of what happens sometimes: http://i42.tinypic.com/5lv21t.png